# data extraction and its summation using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

I have a following data representation in an text file called as

data.txt

```
03/05/2016 11:00  50

03/05/2016 11:10  10

03/05/2016 11:20  30

03/05/2016 11:30  40

03/05/2016 11:40  40

03/05/2016 11:50  50

03/05/2016 11:60  70

03/05/2016 12:00  25

03/05/2016 12:10  69

03/05/2016 12:20  25

03/05/2016 12:30  59

03/05/2016 12:40  25

03/05/2016 12:50  29

03/05/2016 12:60  25
```

I want to perform  certain mathematical operation such that i can obtain the end result as

```
03/05/2016 11:00 - 12:00 290

03/05/2016 12:00 - 13:00 257
```

where this result  is stored in another text file say data1.txt

here 290 is the sum of data from 11:00 to 12:00 and 257 is the sum of the data from 12:00 to 13:00

I want to write this code in python 2.7

How can i achieve this....

```
**UPDATED**


import time 
import datetime

while 1:
    final_sensorvalue = 0
    st_time = time.time()
    crntdatetime = 0.0

    while ((time.time() - st_time) < 600.0):
        sensorvalue = 10 # read sensor value
        final_sensorvalue = final_sensorvalue + sensorvalue
        time.sleep(2)




    f = open('data.txt','a')
    crntdatetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = crntdatetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

    outstring = str(timestamp)+"  "+str(final_sensorvalue)+ "\n"
    print outstring
    f.write(outstring)
    f.close()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you have written so far?

Comment: @salomonderossi updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the lines to [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects where the key is date & hour (`'03/05/2016 11'`) and value is number as `int`. Then you could add all the `Counter` objects together, sort the items and write them to a file:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    res = sum((Counter({x.group(1): int(x.group(2))})
               for x in (re.search('(.*?):.*\s(\d+)', line) for line in f) if x),
              Counter())

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('{0}:00 - {1}:00 {2}\n'.format(k, int(k.split()[-1]) + 1, v)
                 for k, v in sorted(res.iteritems()))
```

Contents of `output.txt`:

```
03/05/2016 11:00 - 12:00 290
03/05/2016 12:00 - 13:00 257
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
fo = open("data.txt","r")
lines = fo.readlines()
#print lines
d={}

for i in range(0,len(lines),2):
    l = lines[i].split()
    if int(l[1].split(":")[0]) != 23:
        time = l[1].split(":")[0] + ":00-" + str(int(l[1].split(":")[0])+1) +":00"
    else:
        time = l[1].split(":")[0] + ":00-0:00"
    #key = l[0]+"_"+l[1].split(":")[0]
    key = l[0]+"_"+time
    if key in d:
        d[key] = int(d[key]) + int(l[2])
    else:
        d[key] = int(l[2])
print d


>>> 
{'03/05/2016_11:00-12:00': 290, '03/05/2016_12:00-13:00': 257}
```